# MapKit: How to add a new map layer from very large images

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mapkit, apple-maps

I have a ton of large images I need to overlay onto my MapKit view in order to display another map layer that covers the entire United States.

Is there a good way to do this? How could one handle loading only small portions at once to conserve memory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look into something like [TileMill](http://tilemill.com) for chopping the images into geographic tiles and rendering them with something like `MKOverlay` or the [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk).